# Check for the alert in selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am trying the following code

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long

Const NO_JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1"
Const JS_PROFILE As String = "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"

Set bot = New ChromeDriver
Set ws = ActiveSheet
arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row))

With bot
    .SetProfile JS_PROFILE, True
    .Get "https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" & arr(1)
```

I would loop through some mobile numbers stored in the array .. and sometimes there are invalid numbers so I encountered alert message that the number is invlaid
How can I catch this alert and debug in the immediate window that the number is invalid and skip to the next number

I tried the following function

```
Function IsDialogPresent(driver As WebDriver) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
Debug.Print driver.Title
IsDialogPresent = (26 = Err.Number)
End Function
```

and in the main code I declared a variable

```
Dim dlg As Alert
```

then I used

```
  If IsDialogPresent(bot) Then
    Set dlg = .SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)

 Stop
    'Close Alert
    'dlg.Dismiss
 End If
```

but the function doesn't return True as I expected (so it seems not to be alert like I know)

Comment: 1) does IsDialogPresent return True if you step slowly through with F8? 2) Can you continue without interacting with alert and check for some other indication in the htm/jsl?

Comment: No it doesn't return True even if I step using F8 and wait for some time ..If I didn't interact with it the code stops at all. Can you check the code and test it. The url is already there. Just input invalid number in A2 ..

Comment: Afraid I won’t because I won’t use WhatsApp web which I assume you have to? It asks me to connect my phone to machine. You can almost certainly swop that xpath, which is fragile, could be swooped with a shorter css selector.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried so many tries and the following could solve it - but I welcome any other suggestions or ideas

```
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
            If .FindElementsByXPath("//*[@id='app']/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]").Count > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "The Mobile " & arr(i, 1) & " Not Valid Number."
                .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='app']/div/span[2]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div").Click
                GoTo Skipper
            End If
```